# How does Nexus Pro auto-verify the authenticy of the downloaded artifacts?

Tags: security, maven, build, nexus, pgp

I have done some research on the Maven Central Repository security, especially the Cross Build Injection attack (XBI). I read a few links, which I listed below:

http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/01/how-to-generate-pgp-signatures-with-maven/

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html

[Verification of dependency authenticy in Maven POM based automated build systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307146/verification-of-dependency-authenticy-in-automated-build-systems)

Here are the key points I understand

1. All upload to Central repository requires the artifacts being signed
   by PGP private key owned by the release manager of the open source
   project.
2. The public key should be submitted to the key server such
   as MIT key server
3. Manual verification of the downloaded artifacts is
       cumbersome.
4. Repository Manager such as Nexus Pro provides feature to auto-verify the signature of downloaded artifacts.

However, how does Nexus Pro do automatic verification? Does Nexus maintain a repository of PGP keyid of all the open source projects that Maven Central hosts? Does sonatype verifies and sign the PGP public key that open source projects upload to the key server? Anyone knows the internals?

Answer (score 0):

All the GPG keys are available on public key servers and Nexus verifies against those for each downloaded component. Each upload to Central requires a known, registered and approved key.

More details about the process are at https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide

Comment: Not that this adds much/any security as anybody can upload a faked key and generate a signature with it.

Comment: Not true. You can not upload unless you have permissions via a separate system. See all the docs at http://central.sonatype.org

Comment: I was not talking about uploads. The PGP checking on download is supposed to defend against modified artifacts. Any anybody who can modify them can also sign them with any other signature.

Comment: Ye.. but you can not modify them upstream. You would have to do a man in the middle attack on it all. And considerably difficult if you access Central via https as you should if you are concerned about security like that..